# Failed opening 'pages/' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\pear') index.php on line 18

Tags: php, .htaccess, warnings, pear, permission-denied

When I make the project with .htaccess file, I got an error.

1. The first error is

> include(D:\learnphp\drupal-7.43\site\pages): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in D:\learnphp\site\index.php on line 18

2. The second one is

> include(): Failed opening 'pages/' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\pear') in
>   D:\learnphp\drupal-7.43\site\index.php on line 18

Here is my index.php

```
<?php

// Moved functions to their own file so we can use them in page files.
include('includes/functions.php');

// If this is index.php, we won't get a path, so we need to set it.
$path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : 'home.php';


// Render featured products.
$featured_product_output = render_product(get_setting('featured_product_ids'));

// Get some variable to use in the templates.
$company_name = get_setting('company_name');
$year = date('Y');

// Include the file that matches the path name.
include('pages/' . $path);

include('includes/page-template.php');
```

Here is .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions / ownership of the directories *D:\learnphp\drupal-7.43\site\pages*.

It's import that user *php* (the user that executes your php scripts) has access to the files to include.

Normally, it's enough for directories to have 0755 permissions and for php files 0644.

Comment: How can I make the thing that you said in Window 8.1?

Comment: How can I make the thing that you said in Window 8.1? @schellingerht