# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in D:\learnphp\drupal-7.43\site\index.php on line 31

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, php-5.5, parse-error

> I have search through [Parse error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) and I didn't see T_INCLUDE. So
>   I can't solve this problem.

I use *.htaccess* file for php and I solve the *[PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306859/failed-opening-pages-for-inclusion-include-path-c-program-files-x86-de)* problem. After that I got another problem as you can see in title. Please somebody tell me how to solve that error.

```
<?php

// Start the session.
session_start();

// Moved functions to their own file so we can use them in page files.
include('includes/functions.php');

// Connect to the database.
db_connect();

// If this is index.php, we won't get a path, so we need to set it.
$path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : 'home.php';


// Render featured products.
$featured_product_output = render_product(get_setting('featured_product_ids'));

// Get some variable to use in the templates.
$company_name = get_setting('company_name');
$year = date('Y');

// Show log in / log out links.
$login_logout = '<a href="login.php">Log in </a>';
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $login_logout = '<a href="login.php"My account</a> | <a href="login.php?action=logout>Log out</a>';
}

// Include the file that matches the path name.
require 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\pear\PEAR.php'
include('pages/' . $path);

$notices = get_notices();

include('includes/page-template.php');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to write **';'** at the end of line 30:
require 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\pear\PEAR.php'